# Steam web api Linking accounts

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

Hello i am trying to find information on how to proceed with linking steam account for example like epic games have on their website where you can link your steam account to epic games account , to be able to login and use web api

Comment: Your question is not belong to programming. Do not ask questions of non-programming on stackoverflow.

Comment: My questing belongs to where i put my tags on steam web api :)

Answer (score 0):

Steam OpenID Provider can be used to login and authenticate user witch will return steamID and allow to interact with web api
https://steamcommunity.com/dev